# How to restrict subscribe to fire on init for dropdown having a value binded OnLoad?

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I do know `Subscribe` wont fire onload (Init) as per documentation .

But what i have here is bit different and let me try explaining my scenario

I am having a dropdownlist and set of other controls in my create page . Dropdwonlist having a set of listitems when i select something `susbscribe` will fire (i subscribed dropdown selected value) and inside subscirbe i will do a ajax call and fill the data in remaining controls and i can `MODIFY` data in other controls which came based on dropdwon selection and finally i will save .

**Html:**

```
  <select  data-bind="options:CtList,optionsValue:'Value',optionsText:'Text',optionsCaption:'--Select--',value:CSelected">
```

Till this point everything works so great but when i take the `created id` and come to the page i saved before with modifications those are gone and i can see values which are related to dropdwon selection on my page `subscribe effect`.

**View Model Code:**

```
self.CSelected =  ko.observable("");

self.CSelected.subscribe(function (selected) {
if(selected != undefined)
{ //make a ajax call and load vlaues on success  }
});
```

Truly thats how it tend to happen on `OnLoad` in this scenario as there is a value for dropdown  (i saved dropdown selected value and loading back) .

Any way to restrict the `subscribe` firing on load if i have a value but it should fire when i change selection . If the same thing can be done using any better approach do enlighten me .

I got this **working** but i am not satisfied still iam looking for perfect solution using KnockOut .

**My code:**

```
var loadcount =0;
self.CSelected.subscribe(function (selected) {
if(selected != undefined) {
if(loadcount >0)
{//make a ajax call and load vlaues on success  }
loadcount++;
}
else
{loadcount++;}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the subscribe after filling in the `CSelected` saved value, not before.

```
self.CSelected =  ko.observable("");
...
// fill CSelected 
self.CSelected(savedValue);
...
self.CSelected.subscribe(function (selected) {
    if(selected != undefined)
    { //make a ajax call and load vlaues on success  }
});
```

Comment: bit confused mate . saved value  ? dropdown value or  created id  ? if you are refering to dropdown selected save value it will inturn use `self.CSelected`

Comment: `self.CSelected(self.CSelected())` something like this ?

Comment: When you reload a page, you set `CSelected` with a saved value. Where do you do that? The subscribe must occur after that.

Comment: yes once after `self.CSelected()` is filled with immediate effect subscribe is getting fired and replacing existing values but how to prevent that ? . i am getting my existing values under ajax success call . something like `if (createdid >0) { //ajaxcal to load data inc dropdownlist in success} else {//load dropdown having listitems }`

Comment: hope i am not clear with my question i'm afraid . let me try again in simple way . onload in my success function once after `cSelected` is filled i don't want to fire a subscribe and i want to avoid it at any cost .